# I need to get news article data. I'm using request/get from python but I got this error: 403 forbidden

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Here is the code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://business.inquirer.net/category/latest-stories/page/10'
response = get(url)
print(response.text[:500])
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
```

And this is the result i got:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read that putting a header will solve the error but I tried putting the header which i copied from the devtool when i inspected the site but it doesn't solve my problem
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including a header, many sites block requests without headers:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=...)
```

Check the requests docs for more info: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

You don't use headers variable anywhere so, you don't pass it with a request. You can do that with code like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

siteurl = "https://business.inquirer.net/category/latest-stories/page/10"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(siteurl,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

When try to scrape data from this site with using `BeautifulSoap` site doesn't display their data.

When you try :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

url = "https://business.inquirer.net/category/latest-stories/page/10"

open_page = urlopen(url)
source = BeautifulSoup(open_page,"html.parser")

print source
```

You will see a line like :

```
<p>The owner of this website (business.inquirer.net) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (4af0dedd3eebcb40-ua48).</p>
```

So dont attent to do it with using `BeautifulSoap` . Using `Selenium` is more easier.

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'your driver path')
driver.get('https://business.inquirer.net/category/latest-stories/page/10')

x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id='ch-ls-head']")


for a in x:
  print a.text
driver.close()
```

OUTPUT :

```
TAXATION
DOF clarifies: Rice tariffication law takes effect on March 5
FEBRUARY 19, 2019 BY:  BEN O. DE VERA
BANKS
HSBC reports net profit at $12.6B in 2018
FEBRUARY 19, 2019
CURRENCIES
Asian shares gain on hopes for progress on China-US trade
FEBRUARY 19, 2019
ECONOMY
Amro sees higher PH growth in 2019 on easing inflation, infra boost
FEBRUARY 19, 2019 BY:  BEN O. DE VERA
TELECOMMUNICATIONS
Poe to DICT: Stop ‘dilly-dallying’ over 3rd telco project
FEBRUARY 19, 2019 BY:  CHRISTIA MARIE RAMOS
SOCIAL SECURITY
SSS contribution collections grow by P22.19B in 2018
FEBRUARY 18, 2019 BY:  CHRISTIA MARIE RAMOS
STOCKS
World stocks mixed ahead of further China-US trade talks
FEBRUARY 18, 2019
TRADE
Rice tariffication starts on March 3
FEBRUARY 18, 2019 BY:  BEN O. DE VERA
AGRICULTURE/AGRIBUSINESS
NFA-Bohol workers wear black to mourn ‘death of the rice industry’
FEBRUARY 18, 2019 BY:  LEO UDTOHAN
BONDS
Treasury: RTBs to be sold to individual investors online in Q1
FEBRUARY 18, 2019 BY:  BEN O. DE VERA
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply worked for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://business.inquirer.net/category/latest-stories/page/10') 
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
print (text)
```